# Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined after parse executes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My problem is in the parse function I think:

```
/*global define */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/article'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Article) {
    'use strict';

    var Articles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Article,
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts",

        initialize: function() {
        },

        parse: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });

    return new Articles();
});
```

I got this error after the parse function is executed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined
```

for example when I set return response.somthing; instead of return response; there is no error message.

and here is the response object:

```
[
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "price": 0,
      "category": "test",
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "price": 0,
      "category": "test",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "price": 0,
      "category": "test",
      "id": 2
    },
]
```

and here is my model declaration:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            price: 0,
            category: ''
        },

        initialize: function() {
        }

    });

    return new Article();
});
```

Comment: I just posted an answer but my general theme is that I don't think you need `parse` per se because you can let it do the default parsing, ie you have no custom parsing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the client (where the `sync` or `fetch` actually resides, for instance) but I would venture the following:

The function `parse` is taking as an argument `response` and returning it.

`response` is whatever the server is returning as `JSON`.

A `Backbone` model is more than just its `JSON` representation; it is wrapping that `JSON` and giving it more functionality (like the `idAttribute` for instance).

So by returning `response` you are just returning some array (based on your `response` you posted).

Instead of using `parse`, I would just let the default method do whatever it does, because it looks like your `response` is already ready to be parsed.

What I would do is to first return the type instead of the instance from your `define`d modules for `Article` and `Articles`:

**In `models/article.js`**

```
return Article; // not return new Article;
```

**In your collection definition**

```
return Articles; // not return new Articles;
```

Now, from your client:

```
var articlesCollection = new Articles();
```

You fetch the collection:

```
articlesCollection.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        // now collection is a reference to articlesCollection and it will have models in it collection.models
    },
    error: function(collection, response) {
    }
```

When you do, you'll have by default the following sort of models:

**`collection.at(0)`**

```
Article
   attributes: { all your properties from the JSON of each object }
```

Does this clarify things at all?